# 2009 Hyundai Accent not starting after replacing crank shaft sensor

Tags: starting, crankshaft

My car died on the road last Thursday with a P0345 code. This indicated the crankshaft position sensor was faulty.  Replaced the sensor and now the car does not start. There are no codes presented now either. The engine cranks fine.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Found the new part to be defective. Put the old sensor back in and get the P0345 code.Ordering a new one.

Comment: welcome to the site :) if you fixed this would you post an answer to your own question so other users can also see the fix!